# karate netty server - How to send PDF/ZIP files as a netty server response?

Tags: karate

How to send PDF/ZIP files as a netty server response? - We have requirement to mock the statement generation where PDF files needs to sent as API response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be easy, just set the `response` as a byte-array, set the proper `Content-Type` header, and Karate should do the rest:

```
Scenario: pathMatches('/v1/binary/download')
    * def responseHeaders = { 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream' }
    * def Utils = Java.type('com.myco.Utils')
    * def response = Utils.getPdfAsByteArray()
```

If you see a problem, please try with beta version 0.9.0.RC3 and let me know.

Comment: Perfect. worked well in version 0.7.0 itself. Thanks a lot Peter.